# Ubuntu Studio installer not detecting hard drive

Tags: system-installation, usb, hard-drive

Got a new Acer Aspire A315-56 with Windows 10 preinstalled, have been trying to install Ubuntu Studio 21.10 from a USB over it, installer seems to not recognize the hard drive. I get these errors:

"There is not enough drive space. At least 16 GiB is required." (Windows 10 displays that I have 475 GB.)

"There are no partitions to install on." (I'm fairly certain there are partitions on the hard drive considering Windows is already on the drive.)

I'm not sure what's happening here, I've tried this on other laptops and they've worked fine. If anyone could give me a hand here I'd appreciate it.

UPDATE: Rewriting the USB with Rufus fixed the partitions error, but not the drive space error.

UPDATE 2: So yes, the issue was that it wasn't recognizing my hard drive. The process to get it to be recognized was way more convoluted than I thought; essentially I had to disable secure boot, then change the SATA mode to AHCI. The process for doing this was very hidden and it took hours to find a process, which I entirely blame Acer for.

Comment: Your windows filesystem may be encrypted wiith bitlocker. If so, you need to go to the microsoft website and unlock it. Google 'how to turn off bitlocker.' Until it is turned off, you won't be able to install another os. Windows claims the entire hard drive(s). If it is encrypted, other platforms may not detect it. EDIT: didnt see the last para. Answer so we know it is solved. Thanks

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't know that. I'm new to stackexchange, sorry.

Comment: All good. In this case, it is as simple as clicking `answer` button and copy / pasting your last paragraph into the box, then clicking submit. Currently the question shows up in searches as having 0 answers. If anyone in the future is looking for the answer, they likely will not click for this reason, so a.) they won't be helped, and b.) you wont get the upvote / rep.